# How to call .NET function/method from Quartz

Tags: vb.net, quartz.net

I know that many examples on the website are in C# although but I want to call a .NET function/method from Quartz and I'm using VB.Net.

Many examples describe about how to open file/application/exe and so on which is external to .NET ... but I want to call something internal (vb function/method)

How can i do that please? is it possible?

**Please see below.**

```
'define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
        .WithIdentity(myMethod(), "group1")
        .Build();



Sub myMethod()
    MsgBox("YES")
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't call a method from Quart, but Quartz scheduler calls your method. Create a class that implements IJob. In that class add a method Execute() and pass your class to Quart.Net. Schedule the job, run Quartz and it will call your Execute() method.

Comment: Thanks so much !!! Please can you provide me with a VB.Net example. Even C# if you can't write VB.Net code please.

Comment: I have translated a C# code sample to VB.Net and worked fine. Just need to add Quartz.Net from NuGet package to a VB.Net console project and use that code.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you create a class (that implements `IJob`), write a method `Execute` and put your code there. Please check out [this tutorial](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html), it explains how to run the scheduler and pass the job. I have translated full sample code to VB.Net and tested it.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Quartz
Imports Quartz.Impl
Imports Quartz.Job

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Try
            Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = New Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter() _
                With {.Level = Common.Logging.LogLevel.Info}

            ' Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
            Dim scheduler As IScheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler()

            ' and start it off
            scheduler.Start()

            ' define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
            Dim job As IJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create(Of HelloJob)().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").Build()

            ' Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
            Dim trigger As ITrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1").StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(Function(x) x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever()).Build()

            ' Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)

            ' some sleep to show what's happening
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))

            ' and last shut down the scheduler when you are ready to close your program
            scheduler.Shutdown()
        Catch se As SchedulerException
            Console.WriteLine(se)
        End Try

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Class HelloJob
        Implements IJob
        Public Sub Execute(context As IJobExecutionContext) Implements IJob.Execute
            Console.WriteLine("Greetings from HelloJob!")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

The next thing is learning how to define *Cron expressions*. For example to run the job every Monday or the first day of every month. Your console application can then be deployed as a Windows Service that runs automatically on start up and calls your Execute method when is due.